# Using R to web scrape parts of a table

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, html-nodes

I'm trying to use R to scrape certain elements from a table on a website. I think I'm just making simple syntax errors, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(string)

testlinkurl <- "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202209080ram.htm"
testlinkpage <- read_html(testlinkurl)
```

Here's what the page looks like:

[image]

...and here's the source code for it.

[image]

I'm trying to scrape the teams and the quarter scores from the table and put it into a csv. I've tried a few code snippets without success:

```
row <- html_attr(html_nodes(testlinkpage, xpath="//class="visitor center""))%>%  html_table()
Error: unexpected symbol in "row <- html_attr(html_nodes(testlinkpage, xpath="//class="visitor"

row <- html_attr(html_nodes(testlinkpage, xpath="//*table[@class='statistics']"))
Warning message:
In xml_find_all.xml_node(x, make_selector(css, xpath)) :
  Invalid expression [1207]

row <- html_attr(html_nodes(testlinkpage, xpath='/*[@id="content"]')) %>% html_table()
list()
```

Any and all input would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)


tbl <- rvest::read_html('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202209080ram.htm') %>% 
  rvest::html_elements('.linescore') %>% 
  rvest::html_table()

tbl[[1]] %>% 
  setNames(c('rm', 'Team', "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Final")) %>% 
  select(-rm)


#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   Team                Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4 Final
#>   <chr>            <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 Buffalo Bills        7     3     7    14    31
#> 2 Los Angeles Rams     0    10     0     0    10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>